# Getting friend list from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to tables in MySQL database, USERS and FRIENDS. They have this structure:

USERS TABLE:

[image]

FRIENDS TABLE (two users are friends ONLY if exists two rows like in the image):

[image]

I want to create a MySQL query in PHP to SELECT the nombre (name) of the users that are my friends. I read that I have to use the operator LEFT JOIN but I did not succeed.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your try with `JOIN`? Probably an `INNER JOIN` is better here

Comment: Can you show what queries you have tried and explain why those are not returning what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `INNER JOIN` instead. Try below query -

```
SELECT users.nombre FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON 
(users.id = friends.usuari_o OR users.id = friends.usuari_t)
WHERE (friends.usuari_o = $id OR friends.usuari_t = $id);
```

Comment: yes, it's good! but I need to use a variable that I send to the php, to check my friends, that is my id  ($id). How can I add this condition?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself.. IT WORKS! Can I do it efficiently? 3 selects in one query..

```
  SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id IN 
(SELECT usuari_one FROM friends WHERE usuari_two='$id')
 AND (SELECT usuari_two FROM friends WHERE usuari_one='$id')
```